# How can I parse a csproj file with Roslyn to get the list of imported target files?

Tags: roslyn

I know I can do it with bare XML, but I am curious if Roslyn lets me do it too.

My current code is:

```
MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();

using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
{
    workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = true;
    var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionFile);
    foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
    {
        foreach (var csFile in project.Documents.Where(o => o.SupportsSyntaxTree && o.Name.EndsWith(".cs")))
        {
            // Do some per cs file processing
        }

        // I want to check the imports and if the one I need is missing - add it.
    }
}
```

How can I extract the information about the imports? Preferably with the FullSpan positions, so I could edit the original file conveniently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roslyn doesn't know anything about MSBuild.  The MSBuildWorkspace  uses an instance of MSBuild that is installed on your machine to calculate the commandline that would be passed to the compiler.  If you want to examine the project files themselves I would look at using the MSBuild apis, specifically [ProjectRootElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.construction.projectrootelement?view=netframework-4.7.1) and  [Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project?view=netframework-4.7.1)